# Compatibility Levels for migration old SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to migrate sql server databases from SQL 2000 and 2005 to 2016.

The whole process is clear for me, but i'm wondering if the problem will occurs when i will change Compatibility Level from 80/90 to 130.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change compatibility levels you may disrupt some functionalities.
Compatibility levels allow a database to use an higher engine than its functionalities.

So when you go for higher compatibility levels, you may break the code that uses obsolete functions.
That's why you have to make sure the software is fully compatible with the target SQL version.

So migration process is the following for 2000 bases.
First make sure you dont break code by using obsolete functions.
Migration from 2000 to 2008 and change compatibility level.
Then migrate from 2008 to 2016 and change compatibility level.

References :
[Difference between compatibility level and database version](http://sqlrus.com/2014/10/compatibility-level-vs-database-version/)

Comment: So what should be proper way to migrate database from 2000 to 2016?

Comment: First you have to make sure, your software does not use obsolete functions. Then if ok, migrate from 2000 to 2008, change compatibility level to 2008 then migrate from 2008 to 2016 and change the compatibility level to 2016.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hybris ! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of the differences between each compability level here - you'll have to work through the changes at each step:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level

It doesn't seem to go as far back as to cover changes between 80 and 90, for that, see this dba.se post for some comparisons:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44908/what-is-the-actual-behavior-of-compatibility-level-80